# perl -- send hash from one script to another one (Child parent)

Tags: json, perl

I'm working on a script which forks a child (just one at a time). The child queries the DB and should return back the results, which are in a hash, to the parent. What's the best way to communicate from child to parent? Currently I'm using the following code:

**Parent:**

```
                  close WRITER;
              chomp(my $line = <READER>);
              logEntry("Parent Pid $$ received panelist listing.");
              print '-------------------------';
              print $line ; 
              print '-------------------------';
              %cached_panelists_hash = %{ decode_json $line };
```

#                 close READER;

**Child:**

```
    my $json = encode_json \%cached_panelists_hash;
    close READER;
    print WRITER $json;
    close WRITER;  # this will happen anyway
```

But this one fails *sometimes*, because no data is sent and the parent dies (JSON malformed -- no data is there to be malformed!)

Comment: Please share the full code, including access to the DB from the child. Also, using the same var `%cached_panelists_hash` in the child and the parent is confusing, I suggest naming them differently.

Comment: The [Storable module](http://perldoc.perl.org/Storable.html) is an option.

Comment: The reason i use the same variable is that child should use data in it.

Answer (score 2):

A collection of some solutions that may or may not work for you:

#### Threading

Inter-Process Communication is painful. Perl has support for threading (although that threading implementation is painful as well). It allows you to mark variables as shared, which might come in useful here. But threads can also return values:

```
use threads;

my $query_db_thread = threads->create(\&query_db);

...; # do other stuff at the same time.

my $results = $query_db_thread->join();

sub query_db { ... } # normal sub that returns your data.
```

The semantics of Perl threading are *similar* to forking, i.e. the threads work with seperate copies of what looks like the same variable (except when explicitely shared).

Using functional programming principles can make your programs easier threadable.

#### Storable module

You could also serialize your data with e.g. the [`Storable`](https://metacpan.org/module/Storable) module. The documentation has some nice examples that cover packing and unpacking. In short:

```
use Storable qw/freeze thaw/;

# In child:
print PARENT freeze(\%data);

# in parent:
local $/; binmode CHILD;
my $data = thaw(<CHILD>);
```

Storable is “better” than JSON because JSON cannot transmit all Perl data structures, like objects.

#### The simplest solution.

If your child doesn't want to return a result, and wants to communicate that to a parent, there are various ways of signaling that. Like returning a non-JSON-value. Your parents reads the maybe-JSON, checks for this special value, and either decodes the JSON (if the marker wasn't found), or handles the error. The empty string would make for a nice marker.